# Showing commits ahead of a SHA

Tags: git

In git, how can I view a commit ahead of a SHA. I am trying to see the commit log around a specific SHA.

`git log <SHA>` is useful, but only shows previous SHAs.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --reverse --ancestry-path <sha>^..master`